# "Minkowski's inequality" taking on negative functions in $L^p$ confusion

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces

Does the "Minkowski inequality" imply that

$||f_n-f||_p=||f_n+-f||_p \leq ||f_n||_p + ||-f||_p =  ||f_n||_p -||f||_p?$

Comment: If $\|x\|=\|x-y+y\|\leq\|x-y\|+\|y\|$, then $\|x\|-\|y\|\leq\|x-y\|$. Changing the roles of $x$ and $y$ we have $\|y\|-\|x\|\leq\|x-y\|$. Thus $|\|x\|-\|y\||\leq\|x-y\|$. So this is true not only in $L_p$, but in the arbitrary normed space.

Comment: Note that $\lVert -f  \rVert = \lVert f  \rVert.$

Comment: @blat so to answer my question, the answer is no? The minkowski doesn't imply what I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it does not.

The problem is in the last "$=$" sign.
In particular, $\|-f\|_p = -\|f\|_p$ is false,
if $f\neq0$.
Instead,
$$
\|-f\|_p = \|f\|_p
$$
is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Norms are absolutely homogeneous, meaning that $\lVert \alpha f \rVert = |\alpha| \lVert f \rVert$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}.$ So your last equality doesn't follow. In fact $\lVert -f \rVert = \rVert f \lVert.$